# Extending a trait by an object

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I have a Class named `A` that extends a Trait `X`. `X` has an abstract variable `x` that has been implemented in the class `A`. Class `A` uses one of the functions in Trait `X` named `foo`. I am trying to make a companion object of Class `A` and put in some 'static' method inside it named `Ofoo`. My problem is that `Ofoo` uses `foo`. So, I tried doing something like this:

```
trait X{
val x:String
def foo = {
    //Full implementation here
    }
}

case class A extends X{
val x = "barbaz"
// Class uses foo
}

object A extends X{
def Ofoo = {
    //This also needs to use foo
    }
}
```

I get an error saying the object `A` cannot be instantiated as the variable `x` is not defined in trait `X`.
How should I structure `A` such that it can use the function `foo` defined in the trait `X`?

Comment: You should explain what you are really trying to accomplish (your real problem, not an abstraction of it).  There is probably a simple solution, but it is hard to say if we don't really know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler behaves as it should. There can be 2 things: Does `foo` use `x`?

If that is the case then it is required to have an Instance with `x` declared as the compiler says. You could say:

```
object A{
    def ofoo = new X{val x = "default"}.foo
}
```

If `foo` does not use `x` then I am not sure if it should even belong to the trait `X`. You could then create an `object X` and then have `foo` inside it something like:

```
trait X{
   val x:String
}

object X{
   def foo = {}
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I can put the function `foo` in an object but how will I then make sure that only class `A` (and its singleton object `A`) can access it?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure then.

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing `x` in `A`? It's just an object; it has to obey the same rules, which include implementing the abstract members of any classes/traits that are being extended.

```
object A extends X {
  val x = "hello"
  ...
}
```

just because it's the companion object of a `class A` that already inherits from `X` and implements `x`, does not mean that `object X` somehow magically reuses it.

In fact, technically a class and it's companion object are not connected; their only relation exists by convention.

---

On the other hand, if you want to make sure the value of `x` is the same in both class `A` as well as object `A`, you can just define `val x` in `object A` and pull in that value in `class A`:

```
class A extends X {
  val x = X.x
  ...
}
object A extends X {
  val x = "shared-value-of-x"
  ...
}
```

Comment: "In fact, technically a class and it's companion object are not connected; their only relation exists by convention." Not quite: they see each other's private methods and fields.

Answer (score 0):

At any rate, x must be defined by object A or in one of its superclasses/supertraits.

Based of the previous proposals and the OP's responses, I'll assume that foo should not be accessible from elsewhere, thus:

```
package pack {

  trait X{
    val x:String
  }

  // Reachable only in the same source file
  sealed trait Y extends X{

   // if foo doesn't use x below, no need to extend X, though
   private[pack] def foo = {
      //Full implementation here
      println("x = "+x)
    }
  }

  case class A() extends X with Y{
    val x = "barbaz"
    // Class uses foo
    foo
  }

  object A extends X with Y{
    val x = "barbatruc" 
    def ofoo = {
      //This also needs to use foo
      foo
    }
  }

}
```

Actually I have a hard time to understand what the OP wants. I agree with toto2.